# SQL query to consider exactly last 3 email send count and then return the respective click count

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, window-functions

I have a table - 'clicks_plus_noClicks_raw' like below

```
EmailAddress  sentdate               clickdate               pid
a@gmail.com   15 August 2021 23:30                            4000
b@gmail.com   15 August 2021 23:30                            5000
b@gmail.com   15 August 2021 23:30                            5000
b@gmail.com   15 August 2021 23:30                            5000
b@gmail.com   16 August 2021 23:30                            5000
c@gmail.com   16 August 2021 23:30   17 August 2021 23:30     5000
b@gmail.com   16 August 2021 23:30                            8000



Expected results
 EmailAddress            pid          count
 b@gmail.com             5000         0
```

If customer has not clicked on any of the last 3 emails we sent(exact 3), I want to add the result to final table with count as 0.

a@gmail.com & b@gmail.com should be skipped because we dint send them 3 emails yet.The final results should be only for ones we sent 3 emails.

I have this query, but the query counts even last 1 send, which is not what I want.

```
select t1.EmailAddress, t1.pid,count(case when rn <= 3 then t1.clickdate else null end) as Clickcount   
from (  
select t1.EmailAddress, 
t1.pid, 
row_number() over(partition by t1.EmailAddress, t1.pid order by t1.sentdate desc) rn,   
t1.clickdate    
from clicks_plus_noClicks_raw t1    
) t1    
group by t1.EmailAddress,t1.pid
```

Comment: What is the column pid?

Comment: pid is the product_id

Comment: What does it have to do with the requirement? Why do you use it inside row_number()?

Comment: to count the row by pid, if that is confusing I will delete the sql i addded

Comment: The last email sent to b@gmail.com has pid=8000. Why it is not in the results?

Comment: because, it should be skipped as well, we dint send 3 emails for product_id 8000 for b@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `HAVING` clause in your query to check for the number of emails and a `WHERE` clause to return only the last 3 emails:

```
SELECT EmailAddress, 
       pid,
       COUNT(clickdate) count
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmailAddress, pid ORDER BY sentdate DESC) rn
  FROM clicks_plus_noClicks_raw
) t
WHERE rn <= 3
GROUP BY EmailAddress, pid
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a0d15a694891456eb8dc55fe62924381).

Comment: thanks for your answer. But when I run this query in SFMC i get an error, like this - "An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Only SELECT queries are valid. Select must be the first word of the query. Old style JOIN (ANSI JOINs) syntax is not allowed. Please use standard syntax. "

Comment: @SoniaS it seems like SFMC does not support CTEs. I edited the query. Try it now.